# Pass Multiple Data Parameters to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a dynamic data table with a button that launches a Bootstrap Modal. In the modal is a form. I need the softwareID to pass from the page to the modal to a hidden field in the form. My modal opens and the form displays fine but, the softwareID field is empty. I have searched the Internet trying all types of code and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code so far:

```html
<div class="col">
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('#upload').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var myVal = $(event.relatedTarget).data('softwareID');
  $(this).find(".modal-body").text(myVal);
});
</script>
 
 <?php
   if (("".($district_results_private->getColumnVal("paid")  ."" == "Y") and "".($logged_user->getColumnVal("tec_member")  ."" == "Y")) or ("".$_GET['state']  ."" != "MA" and ("".($logged_user->getColumnVal("tec_member")  ."" == NULL) or "".($logged_user->getColumnVal("tec_member")  ."" == "N")) and "".$_GET['state']  ."" != "NH" and "".$_GET['state']  ."" != "RI")) {  // WebAssist Show If
?> <button data-softwareID="<?php echo($district_results_private->getColumnVal("softwareID")); ?>" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upload">Create New Request</button><?php
  } // ("".($district_results_private->getColumnVal("paid")  ."" == "Y") and "".($logged_user->getColumnVal("tec_member")  ."" == "Y")) or ("".$_GET['state']  ."" != "MA" and ("".($logged_user->getColumnVal("tec_member")  ."" == NULL) or "".($logged_user->getColumnVal("tec_member")  ."" == "N")) and "".$_GET['state']  ."" != "NH" and "".$_GET['state']  ."" != "RI")
?>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="modal fade" id="upload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadlLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="uploadLabel">Create New Request</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cancel"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label for="supporting_files">Please fill out the following optional information:</label>
            <br><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 col-sm">
            <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon12">Principal/Dean</font></span></div>
            <input name="principal_dean" type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" id="principal_dean" value="" date_approved="principal_dean" title="Principal/Dean">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3 col-sm">
            <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon10">Paid By</span></div>
            <input name="paid_by" type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" id="paid_by" value="" title="Paid By">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3 col-sm">
            <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon11">Cost</span></div>
            <input name="cost" type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" id="cost" value="" title="Cost">
          </div>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="input-group mb-3 col-sm">
            <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon7"><font color="#339933">Grades</font></span></div>
  &nbsp;
  <label for="grade_level3"><i><font size="-1">Check all that apply</font></i></label>
  <table width="60%" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <td scope="row"><label>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="K" id="grade_level_0" />
        K</label></td>
      <td scope="row"><label>
        <input   type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="1" id="grade_level_1" />
        1</label></td>
      <td scope="row"><label>
        <input    type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="2" id="grade_level_2" />
        2</label></td>
      <td scope="row"><label>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="3" id="grade_level_3" />
        3</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input    type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="4" id="grade_level_4" />
        4</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="5" id="grade_level_5" />
        5</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input   type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="6" id="grade_level_8" />
        6</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input   type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="7" id="grade_level_7" />
        7</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="8" id="grade_level_8" />
        8</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input   type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="9" id="grade_level_9" />
        9</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input    type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="10" id="grade_level_10" />
        10</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input   type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="11" id="grade_level_11" />
        11</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="grade_level[]" value="12" id="grade_level_12" />
        12</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
          </div>
<div class="input-group mb-3 col-sm">
            <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon8"><font color="#339933">Content Area</font></span></div>
  &nbsp;
  <label for="grade_level4"><i><font size="-1">Check all that apply</font></i></label>
  <table width="80%" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="English Language Arts" id="content_area_0" />
        English Language Arts</label></td>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Health" id="content_area_1" />
        Health</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Instructional Technology" id="content_area_2" />
        Instructional Technology</label></td>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Library Media" id="content_area_3" />
        Library Media</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Math" id="content_area_4" />
        Math</label></td>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Science" id="content_area_6" />
        Science</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Physical Education" id="content_area_5" />
        Physical Education</label></td>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Visual Performing Arts" id="content_area_8" />
        Visual Performing Arts</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Social Science" id="content_area_7" />
        Social Science</label></td>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Other" id="content_area_10" />
        Other</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="World Language" id="content_area_9" />
        World Language</label></td>
      <td width="50%" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="content_area[]" value="Computer Science" id="content_area_10" />
        Computer Science</label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
          <div class="input-group mb-2 col-sm">
  <div class="input-group-prepend"></div>
  <input title="Requires Media Release" type="text" class="form-control" value="Requires Media Release?" aria-label="Requires Media Release?">
  <div class="input-group-text"> Yes&nbsp;
    <input name="media_release" type="checkbox" value="Y" aria-label="Requires Media Release">
  </div>
          </div><br>
           <div class="input-group mb-3 col-sm">
            <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon12">Purpose</font></span></div>
            <textarea class="form-control col-md-5" aria-label="With textarea" name="purpose"></textarea>
          </div><br>
          <p><strong>VENDOR CONTACT'S INFORMATION</strong> (optional)</p>
          <div class="input-group mb-3  col-sm">
              <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">Contact Name</span></div>
              <input title="Contact" name="contact" type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" id="contact" value="" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3  col-sm">
              <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon4">Contact Email</span></div>
              <input title="Email" name="contact_email" type="email" class="form-control col-md-8" id="contact_email" value="" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="Enter a valid email address.">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3  col-sm">
              <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon5">Contact Phone</span></div>
              <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" id="phone" value="" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="" title="phone">
            </div>
            
          <div class="modal-footer">
           <input name="statusID" type="hidden" value="6">
           <input name="request_submitted_date" type="hidden" id="request_submitted_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
           <input type="hidden" name="districtID" id="districtID" value="<?php echo($logged_user->getColumnVal("districtID")); ?>">
           <input type="text" name="softwareID" id="softwareID" value="">
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Save New Request</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></div>
  </form>
</div>
```